# Redirect to another page does not work in ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have written one ajax post request on aspx page  which will call web method written in its code behind class.This method return url to redirect..All is working fine till success function of ajax call but in success function I'm redirecting to another page ex.

```
   window.location.assign(data.d)
```

I have checked data.d result via alert in success function which is showing correct url but its not rediecting to that page..Plz help..

Full code is here..

This is script:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            $('#loginbtn').click(function() {
                var userName = document.getElementById('uid').value;
                var password = document.getElementById('pwd').value;
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "testAjax.aspx/Authenticate",
                    data: JSON.stringify({ userName: userName, password: password }),
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function(data) { window.location.assign(data.d); },
                    error: function(e) {
                        alert(e.valueOf());
                    }
                });
                //alert("dsf");
            });

        });
    </script>
```

and following is the web method:

```
 [WebMethod]
        public static string Authenticate(string userName, string password)
        {
            try
            {
                return "Home.aspx";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return string.Empty;
            }

        }
```

Please note: If I uncomment alert("dsf"),all works fine it redirects successfully to Home.aspx..But without this alert it wont redirect.

Comment: I see you're trying to access `data.d`. What is `d`? Try `console.log(data);` and see what it gives.

Comment: It gives proper result.I have tested it.

Comment: Even if I hard code url there..It wont work.It works only if there is some alert..In this case alert("dsf");

Comment: *Where* have you tested it? In the `success` function? Because that's where it should be tested. When you say "there", that should not be the place where the `alert` is right now.

Comment: @NicklasNygren Yes I have tested the result in success function only,It gives the correct result,But it wont redirect to Home Page.

Comment: Try setting `async: true`

Comment: @ NicklasNygren I got the solution..Problem was the form tag..When I remove form tag all works gr8..:)..btw thanks for all your help.

Comment: Oh, so `#loginbtn` was part of a `<form>`? And you don't want that?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
success: function(data) {  window.location=data.ToString(); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        $('#loginbtn').click(function() {
            var userName = document.getElementById('uid').value;
            var password = document.getElementById('pwd').value;
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "testAjax.aspx/Authenticate",
                data: JSON.stringify({ userName: userName, password: password }),
                async: false,
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) { window.location=data.d; },
                error: function(e) {
                    alert(e.valueOf());
                }
            });
            //alert("dsf");
        });

    });
</script>
```